# Microservice - Database Security

Tags: sql-server, microservices, self-hosting

We are going the microservices route to try breaking up a monolith. 
Previously we had a single database which was being hit by multiple applications. The applications were given grants to specific table that they need to access.

With microservice architecture we plan to contain a specific domain in a service and the service has its own database.

We use Self hosting windows service to stand up microservices. They all hit SQL server for persistence. We plan to use integrated security for service to authenticate into the database.

This is the point at which the problem starts. To authenticate a service and to ensure that the database is not being used by any other service,we plan to have one service account for each of the applications. Now, for few microservices, management of these accounts (frequent policy based password changes)  are okay. Once the number of services reaches beyond manually manageable scale, we are worried that the account management (1 account per service) will start becoming a pain.

How is this done currently by the industry at large. Are there any tools that we can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 3):

I would solve this by deploying the correct users/credentials to a DB as part of the automated deployment of the service from a continuous integration / continuous deployment server (CI/CD server). You can store the user credentials as `secrets` in the CI/CD server. Additionally cluster infrastructure systems, such as kubernetes, allow you to [store secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) as well.

For example if you use Jenkins for deploying you would include an action in the deployment task to create/update the required user/credentials when the DB and schema are deployed/updated.

Also one important general note - If you are worried about the high number of services, that indicates to me that you may be planning too fine grained services. The general motivation for a service scope is to allow a dedicated `two pizza team` to own a single service and it's complete life cycle. You want to have a developer per service ratio of at least 1 : 1. I don't think you will benefit very much from the Microservices architectural style if you have each developer being responsible for many tiny services.

Here a quote from the [Martin Fowler site](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) (which is a very recommended read btw):

> How big is a microservice?
>
> Although “microservice” has become a popular name for this
>   architectural style, its name does lead to an unfortunate focus on the
>   size of service, and arguments about what constitutes “micro”. In our
>   conversations with microservice practitioners, we see a range of sizes
>   of services. The largest sizes reported follow Amazon's notion of the
>   Two Pizza Team (i.e. the whole team can be fed by two pizzas), meaning
>   no more than a dozen people. On the smaller size scale we've seen
>   setups where a team of half-a-dozen would support half-a-dozen
>   services.
>
> This leads to the question of whether there are sufficiently large
>   differences within this size range that the service-per-dozen-people
>   and service-per-person sizes shouldn't be lumped under one
>   microservices label. At the moment we think it's better to group them
>   together, but it's certainly possible that we'll change our mind as we
>   explore this style further.